# Fusion modules crash

Tags: orange

I try to get Orange 3 working on my Win 8 computer. Everything is fine except the any modules from the FUSION add-on which crash:

Here is the error message.

---

Could not create 'Fusion Graph'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Orange\canvas\scheme\widgetsscheme.py", line 341, in create_widget_instance
    widget.**init**()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\orangecontrib\datafusion\widgets\owfusiongraph.py", line 92, in **init**
    self._create_layout()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\orangecontrib\datafusion\widgets\owfusiongraph.py", line 128, in _create_layout
    self.table = gui.TableWidget(info, select_rows=True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TableWidget'

---

I already tried to re-install but to no avail. Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this issue was just fixed with updates pushed to PyPI.

https://github.com/biolab/orange3-datafusion/issues/16